# add quotaUser to Google Analytics API requests

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm fetching data using the Google Analytics reporting API v4. I do this via python using cron jobs, in order to not over-run my quota and "pass" it to my users I need to setup a `quotaUser` parmeter according to [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/standard_parameters) and [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/parameters) (2nd link is for v3)..

Currently I make my calls like this:

```
    s = analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': start_date, 'endDate': end_date}],
          'metrics': [
                {'expression': 'ga:sessions'},
            ],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:date'}],
        }]
      }
  ).execute()
```

I'm not sure where I should add the `quotaUser` and can I pass any id to it? Could I pass for example the same `VIEW_ID`?? Is that discouraged for any reason?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have a working example right now. But `quotaUser` is a URL parameter, so it will not be in the `body` of the request. I suspect you will need to call it as thus `analytics.reports().batchGet(body=body, quotaUser=True)` and the Python client library will pass that argument to as a URL parameter.

Comment: But I'm supposed to pass an ID with it no?

Answer (score 2):

Matt is right, you add it as parameter to the batchGet call:

```
analytics.reports().batchGet(body={....}, quotaUser="somestring").execute()
```

The library will check if the named parameter is part of the accepted query parameters (e.g. prettyPrint, quotaUser, userip) and add it the the query string if it is.